# Black artifacts on mesh with Cycles, after I set up a normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normals, artifacts

I've been using Blender a lot and I have a commission due to this weekend.

I sculpted a mesh and then retopologyzed it, baked the Normal Map from the Highres to lowres mesh with "Selected to Active" as i've always did.

The problem is, when I lower the camera with Cycles, it will show black artifact on the mesh.[image: Decimated and Retopo'ed]

On the left, there is a mesh that I decimated and on the right the retopology.
[image: Original mesh]

This one is the original mesh, I tried to test the same normal map on the original mesh and the same issue occurs.

I've also tried to open a new file, sculpt on a UV Sphere, then baked the normal.
The issue is still there.[image: Ball]

With this ball I just baked the normal without "Selected to active"

What's the issue here? I thought it was a topology related issue but it happens on normal quad meshes too.

I am on version: 3.2.2, branch: master, commit date: 2022-08-02 18:15, hash: bcfdb14560e7, type: release
build date: 2022-08-02, 23:41:46

Edit, I've also tried on 2.93. Same issue occurs

[image]

Comment: Can you share the sphere file? It can be wrong normal setup, duplicated geometry or maybe something reflects?

Comment: @Crantisz there you go [link](https://mega.nz/file/onpxjLxB#ViwCwAuRS3ae5jMO3bUSHu42KSmPf1eIs2GYHR3b-Zg)

Comment: Kindly use https://blend-exchange.com/ because your link doesn't work for me

Comment: @Crantisz Sorry It's my first time on this website, I think i've added it to the original post with the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color space should be *non-color*, and *normal map* node should be used to convert tangent normal map to object space normals:

[image]

Comment: Amazing. It worked!
Thank you!